# Shoutcast Stream not running in Android Browser - File Is Not Supported Error

Tags: shoutcast

I have android phone and I am trying to run following public Shoutcast stream http://core.crystalone.net:9000/listen.pls  in my phone. However, it is not working and when I open it; it gives me error “File Is Not Supported”.

This is very strange since In Android 2. 2 and higher, I think shoutcast streaming is default and does not require any additional application to play them. I have searched through net and have following questions.

1. Is android by default play shoutcast stream in browser and does not require any additional app or anything? If anything required then can anyone please provide details?
2. Any settings required in my phone to play it by default since if it is required then I can do it? Like make sure that .pls files are played in default media player or something?
3. I have heard a lot about “Tunewiki” and “Streamfurious” so do I need it to install any app or winamp in my phone before I can play this shoutcast streams?
4. Any settings required in shoutcast stream creation in order to get it played in android, I have window based stream with version 1.9.5?

I am out of clue right now and any help will be greatly appreciated.  Also can anyone check this URL in their android and let me know if it runs and if yes, then it runs in browser or in some other way?

***Update***:

I just tried the listen.pls opened in new Motorola touch screen, Android 2.2. It open the default player but then no streaming is done or nothing is played. It is just opening but playing nothing.

Can anyone just confirm that Shoutcast stream will not work on any android phone browser till i install Winamp?

And suppose i install it and i open listen.pls in browser, will it automatically go in winamp to play or will I need to do any setting?

Comment: Hi,

I just tested the stream in my wife's HTC my touch version, having android version 2.2.. Same thing is happening there too. I dont get idea about the player still i hope if anyone can take me out of this.

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to install [Winamp](http://www.appbrain.com/app/winamp/com.nullsoft.winamp) or another Shoutcast-streaming client.

Comment: I just tried the listen.pls opened in new Motorola touch screen, Android 2.2. It open the default player but then no streaming is done or nothing is played. It is just opening but playing nothing. Can anyone just confirm that Shoutcast stream will not work on any android phone browser till i install Winamp? And suppose i install it and i open listen.pls in browser, will it automatically go in winamp to play or will I need to do any setting?

Comment: WinAmp will need to be installed for android systems. You shouldn't have to do anything if it is an iPhone, iPod, etc as they will play and detect the .pls stream.